# Why is this .htaccess evaluating to 302 redirect instead of internal rewrite?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, 302-redirect

As an example, I was expecting this

`https://example.software/credits`

to evaluate to an internal rewrite

`https://example.software?mode=credits`

Why is it showing up on the browser url-bar as a 302 redirect?

```sh
RewriteEngine On
#Put in by the hosting company to enforce https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.software [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.software/$1 [R,L]

#Bunch of domains, not being used yet
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.app$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.app$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.kiwi$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.kiwi$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.nz$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.nz$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.online$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.online$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.software/$1 [R=302,L]

#Internal redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.software$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home$ https://example.software\?mode\=home&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
RewriteRule ^contacts$ https://example.software\?mode\=contacts&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
RewriteRule ^credits$ https://example.software\?mode\=credits&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
RewriteRule ^downloads$ https://example.software\?mode\=downloads&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
RewriteRule ^developer$ https://example.software\?mode\=developer&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
RewriteRule ^projects$ https://example.software\?mode\=projects&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
RewriteRule ^(download)/([^/]+)$ https://example.software?mode=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(code)/([^/]+)$ https://example.software?mode=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(payment)/([^/]+)$ https://example.software?mode=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(donation)/([^/]+)$ https://example.software?mode=payment&name=$2 [L]

Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
Header append X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"
Header append X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
```

Comment: _Aside:_ In your `#Internal redirects` section, the `RewriteCond` directive only applies to the very first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. However, it looks like the intention is that it applies to all the `RewriteRule` directives that follow - but that is not the case. The remaining `RewriteRule` directives are processed unconditionally (ie. for every domain).  To avoid repeating the same condition before every rule, you could instead write an additional rule that _skips_ (`S` flag) the following rules when the requested `Host` is _not_ the domain in question.

Comment: ... although looking at the preceding rule, if you are redirecting all other domains to the domain in question anyway, then maybe that _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) is perhaps redundant anyway. (Unless you are not redirecting _all_ the domains?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rewrite rules use absolute URLs that include the protocol and host name. Internal rewrites only work with relative URLs that have just the path. When mod_rewrite encounters an absolute URL for the target of the rewrite, it uses a redirect.

So instead of

```
RewriteRule ^home$ https://example.software\?mode\=home&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
```

You should use

```
RewriteRule ^home$ /\?mode\=home&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]
```

There are some other possible problems with that rule. I don't think so much needs to escaped, rather than using a variable to append the query string, you should use the QSA (query string append) flag, and you probably need to rewrite to your index handler. The correct rewrite is probably going to look like:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php?mode=home  [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I just changed one of them to test. Its not working for me. To check, I dumped it using `console.log (location.search.substring(1)` but I don't see anything for the internal redirect.

Comment: That code sounds like JavaScript to me. You can't test rewrite rules from JavaScript. You need to use something like curl and your server logs.

Comment: You could do some debugging in your `.htaccess` by using e.g.: `Header always set X-Your-Header "some info"` and inspect that header either in the client console or your server script.

Comment: Almost a year later, it's obviously all working by now - redirection and headers.    But I don't understand your comment.  Please explain what you are trying to impart to me.